# How i can change date format in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, picker

How i can change date format in Date Picker from (19/07/2015) to (2015-07-19)

my Date Picker file :

http://lirz.com/picker.date.js

Comment: Step 1: Open the js file.
Step 2: Go to the link which is written at the third line of the file.
Step 3: Scroll down to options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read [the docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formats) and it looks like this should work.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
})
```

Comment: @BakirOdeh Put it on the page that needs the datepicker.